# Is newer GCC documentation compatible with older documentation?

Tags: gcc, macros, documentation

An example:
In "Using and Porting GCC" (2001), there is the macro SMALL_REGISTER_CLASSES, which tells the compiler to minimize the lifetime of hard registers. Its definition consists of a simple zero / non-zero expression, usually a constant.
In "GCC internals" (2011), the above macro is replaced by the following target hook:
bool TARGET_SMALL_REGISTER_CLASSES_FOR_MODE_P(enum mode)
which is not nearly as neat as the original macro.

Note: Not sure what the difference is between "Using and Porting" and "GCC internals" as far as porting goes (RTL representation, Machine Description and Target Description Modes and Functions). I started by reading the first one thoroughly because that was the suggested documentation, overlooking the fact that it is actually 10 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

At the start of 2001, the current release was 2.95, although 3.0 was already well into development. The current release is 4.6, with 4.7 due in a few months. That's two major release numbers which means two large-scale rewrites of the source code, plus many many other smaller changes that add up to a *lot* of code churn.

Of course, you'll find lots of details that are the same now as ever, but the old documents are not to be trusted.

The current documentation is pretty good, as far as it goes, but it's hardly comprehensive, so if you'd like to improve it as you learn more, I'm sure it'll be appreciated. ;)